# ASP.NET MVC3 Authentication via WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

How do I authenticate via WCF AuthenticationService?

I use this code in `public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)` - method, but it doesn't work if I call IsLoggedIn from other exemple of `AuthenticationServiceClient` - class. AspNetCompatibility is enabled and cookies are allowed.

```
AuthSR.AuthenticationServiceClient client = new AuthSR.AuthenticationServiceClient();
client.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
```

Comment: This is solution!
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515342.aspx
http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/various-clients-and-forms-authentication/
http://www.ben-morris.com/using-the-wcf-authentication-service-without-cookies